# OpenVPN freeradius setting doesn't work

Tags: openvpn

Tell me, I really need to configure OPENVP + FREERADIUS, but Freeradius does not see openvpn users.
openvpn errors:

> 2024-01-10 13:20:22 10.1.1.34:58934 TLS Error: Unroutable control
> packet received from [AF_INET]10.1.1.34:58934 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)
> 2024-01-10 13:20:26 10.1.1.34:58934 TLS Error: Unroutable control
> packet received from [AF_INET]10.1.1.34:58934 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)
> 2024-01-10 13:20:34 10.1.1.34:58934 TLS Error: Unroutable control
> packet received from [AF_INET]10.1.1.34:58934 (si=3 op=P_CONTROL_V1)

Freeradius and openvpn are installed on the same host, I would be very grateful if you could tell me the setup

Comment: Include your config? And what do you mean with "Freeradius doesn't see openvpn users"?